# Can two html elements have the same id but in different classes?

Tags: html, dom, web-frontend

I was writing a javascript for an existing application in which there are two forms with separate **id**s, and in each form there is a `div` which has the id `"validationSummary"`. But these `div`s belong to different classes. So my question is can this be possible? Please anyone can explain me is this correct ?

These are the `div`s:

```
<form id="foo" .....>
<div class="notice_bar validation-summary-errors error_message" id="validationSummary"></div>
</form>

<form id="bar" .....>
<div class="validation-summary-valid notice_bar affirmative_message" id="validationSummary"></div>
</form>
```

and also the class `notice_bar` is common leading to other confusion!

Comment: have you tried it? Yes, it is possible. No, it is not correct. What confusion does common class `notice_bar` lead to?

Comment: IDs are meant to be unique. Use it only once. Referring to the `validationSummary`

Comment: @Igor : the class `notice_bar` now has two `div` elements with the same id. Wouldn't it be a conflict ? BTW this was the answer I was looking for.Thank you.

Comment: @Necromancer - css classes are meant to be used on multiple elements, regardless of the elements' id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possible? Yes. 
Good coding? No.

From [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/types.html#type-name):

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

Answer (score 3):

> A **unique** identifier for the element.
>
> There **must** not be multiple elements in a document that have the same id value.

Taken from [`w3.org`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20121025/global-attributes.html#common.attrs.id).

> The id attribute specifies a unique id for an HTML element (the value must be unique within the HTML document).

Taken from [`W3Schools`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp).

Answer (score 0):

It should work just fine, but it isn't a good practice. Redundancy isn't necessarily a good thing.

Answer (score -1):

It should work...i worked on an app that created the same id, and i use to have same IDs on the page at the same time. It's not good practice because IDs are meant to be unique, but unless you need to use some JavaScript to run something from that specific id (in your case `validationSummary` ) it should work. As already said, it's not what IDs are meant for tho.